Kubuntu 22.04: Thinkpad X1 fingerprint authentication causes login screen to freeze
Yesterday I set up a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon with Kubuntu 22.04 (24.04 is not supported yet for the software we use at my company). I also set up the fingerprint reader with the relevant drivers, as per the instructions on https://blog.rubenwardy.com/2022/11/16/thinkpad-x1-fingerprint-auth/, so that I could use it to log in. This worked fine at the time, where hitting enter when the password box was empty would prompt me for a fingerprint, and subsequently log me into my user's desktop.
Today, when I came to log in, the login screen would freeze when I hit enter. I was still able to move the mouse, but no GUI elements were usable. I was able to switch to a terminal login using Ctrl + Alt + F2, and when logging in with my username here, it would prompt me for a fingerprint and would successfully log me into my user profile in the terminal. After this, I could run startx to get my desktop back.
Notably, if I entered my full password into the Kubuntu login GUI, the screen would still hang and not log me in. After a bit of experimenting, I found that running sudo pam-auth-update and disabling the fingerprint authentication profile would allow me to log in again without issue using my password. This leads me to believe that there is something going awry with the fingerprint authentication service and the Kubuntu login GUI.
What should I start looking at to diagnose why this is happening? I ran sudo journalctl -b to check whether there were any conspicuous things logged here, and I can see the request for a fingerprint being logged when the login GUI is used, but it seems the GUI never displays this request, and placing my fingerprint on the reader doesn't action it either. I'm guessing there is some sort of disconnect between the login environment and the fingerprint service, but don't know where to look to find out more.
